# Working with small functions defined in terms of continuous time intervals

Tags: calculus, functions

$\text{Let us say we have a function } f(t) \text{ which is defined as follows:}$
$f^2(t + \Delta t) = f^2(t) - 3u\Delta t(t - u\Delta t), \text{where }\Delta t \text{ is a small increment in the value of time}.$

$\text{Now, we know that } u \text{ here is a real constant and that } f(0) = a, \text{where }a \text{ is a real constant}$.

$\text{We need to find } t \text{ such that }f(t) = 0.$

$\text{What I have already tried is to integrate the function from 0 to t and then find the final value in terms of a and u}.$

$\text{Can someone help me out please?}$